# How to model an arbitrary number of types

Tags: object-oriented, modeling

I'm currently in the process of modelling a generic form of RNA and RNA transcription and I'm having difficulty finding a proper OO modeling of this area.

Human RNA has 4 types of **Nucleotides** (A, G, U, and C).  An RNA strand is just a string of these 4 types.  eg, AAGACAUUCUA...

What I'm trying to model is more generic in the sense that I want to be able to decide the number of **Nucleotide** types at runtime.  So, my object model needs to be able to represent an arbitrary number **Nucleotide** types.

Initially, I thought I'd just have a **Nucleotide** class which had a **int TypeId** member.  This way, I could have a sequence of **Nucleotide** instances of arbitrary types... but this doesn't feel right.

I'm not a huge fan of storing type in a variable.  I'm also not comfortable with what is essentially *definition* information being set on every instance (instead of being defined in the a class).

So, how do I get around this?  Here's what I've come up with so far:

- On a previous project, we would have Singleton objects which represented another object's type.  The other object would simply reference the singleton and that was it.  It prevented us from having multiple instantiations of the "definition" of our types.  Not too great IMO.
- I remember Entity Framework generating Dynamic Proxies at runtime.  I could so something similar.  I could have a **NucleotideBase** base class and, at runtime, define derived classes.  I believe this is possible through reflection.  I'm not sure what the performance impact is with this approach, but I would assume it's all just one-time overhead when defining the classes.

Are there better, more OO, approaches?

Comment: What difference in behavior is there between two nucleotides of different types?

Comment: Nothing, yet.  A grouping of nucleotides will eventually represent a **codon** (a genetic instruction), but the nucleotides themselves don't do much.  Nucleotides in a strand will get read/parsed and transcribed, but the nucleotide is just data and doesn't do anything itself.  But, to be honest, my knowledge of this is still incomplete, so it is quite possible that the nucleotides types will each eventually have distinct behaviours.

Comment: Your "Not too great IMO" solution is my favorite.  What caused you to dislike it?

Comment: I don't like the idea of "definition" information being stored in an object *instance*.  Using singletons minimizes the ick-factor.  I imagine this must be a fairly common problem, so I assume brighter people than me have found better solutions :)

Comment: It occurs to me that a nucleotide might not deserve its own class at all: If it has no significant behavior, then represent it with, e.g., a character.

Comment: I have thought about that.  I guess you could say that I'm planning for the future where I probably shouldn't be.  There's a good possibility that, later on, I'm going to want to associate Func<>'s to the Nucleotides at runtime.  I thought I would just associate them with the nucleotide instance, but I could do this with a value->Func<> list mapping as well.

Comment: It sounds to me as though you're afraid of your compiler.  If you can partition your code, so that the behavior of your nucleotides is nicely encapsulated, then there's no reason not to recompile the capsule and link it with the precompiled rest of your program.  At that point, you can use a SMALL program to prepare the guts of the capsule, working from a mini-language.  LISP excels at this kind of things, but you can do it in other languages as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a nucleotide has no significant behavior, and if its type information can be represented compactly (for example, a single character), then it doesn't deserve a separate class at all.  Simply represent each nucleotide as a character (or whatever).

If, however, a nucleotide has behavior, then I would model this with singletons, one instance per nucleotide type.

Since there is no difference in behavior in nucleotides, they are simple value objects.  A nucleotide instance should be immutable, so that all nucleotides of a given type can be represented by a single instance.

I would like to use the nucleotide's symbol as its type; this would be the sole instance variable of a Nucleotide.

A nucleotide factory can keep track of the singleton instances of nucleotide, creating a new instance when a new nucleotide type is asked for, or returning an existing instance otherwise.  Depending upon the language, it may be convenient for this factory to be implemented in static methods of the nucleotide class.

Comment: wow, this is *exactly* what I've currently done as a place-holder solution.  We'll see if it becomes my final solution ;)

Comment: I agree. @MetaFight Also, look at it from practical side. RNA is huge. Representing each Nucleotide as separate class would cause huge overhead. So from practical point, representing RNA as simple array of bytes is best solution.

Comment: I'm implementing this in c#.  I was thinking that each occurrence of a nucleotide in an RNA strand would simply be a reference to the singleton Nucleotide of the corresponding type.  This way I can have millions of references to a handful of objects instead of millions of instances.

Comment: @MetaFight Even then, references can take 32/64 bits each, depending on OS. Considering you will probably never need more than 256 Nucleodite types, you can get 4 to 8 times smaller memory footprint when you use simple array of bytes.

Comment: That's a good point.  I'll keep the singleton nucleotide instances because they're conceptually useful, but I'll represent the RNA strand as a list of Nucleotide Keys (TypeId), which would be bytes (for now, as I may actually want more than 256 nucleotide types later).  This should still offer a significant saving in memory as there will always be many *many* more nucleotides than nucleotide types.

Comment: To be pedantic, what you describe isn't a Singleton at all but a flyweight.

Comment: @WayneConrad: well, the gist of the flyweight is **not** to store object references (singleton or not) in each object, but to pass extrinsic context on each method of the flyweight which needs that context from outside, instead of storing the context within the object. See my answer how to implement a flyweight in C# using just 1 byte per TypeId instead of 4. I admit, the Wikipedia article is not very good, better have a look into the original GOF book.

Comment: @Doc Brown, Thanks.  I have to admit, I last read GOF a _long_ time ago.  The language I use now doesn't need much in the way of explicit patterns.

Answer (score 3):

- I would use  `byte TypeId` instead of `int TypeId`, because when you make RNA strands with long lists of Nucleotides, you don't want to waste 4 times of the memory you really need. The `TypeId` should be the only member attribut of that **struct**. If you need additional information for some operations, try to use the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). So a `List<Nucleotide>` with 1000 elements will need almost exactly 1000 bytes in memory, with neglectable overhead (in C#).
- if you don't expect different behaviours for different Nucleotide types, it feels complety wrong for me to use different derived classes for representing the types. Don't overcomplicate things - only because different derived classes can technically be used for distinguishing types, it is not always the best solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  For the case of 4 nucleotide types and a strand of 1000 nucleotides, wouldn't that be 4 instances of the Nucleotide struct (4 * 1 byte) and then 1000 references (1000 * 4 bytes) which adds up to 4004 bytes?

Comment: @MetaFight: you may miss the point that structs are quite different from classes in C#. Say you have your example from above, AAGACAUUCUA, a list of eleven Nucleotides. Gives you eleven instances of the "Nucleotide" class, each one needs just one byte. Structs are **value** types in C#, not reference types, and the memory layout in a generic `List` is AFAIK compact.

Answer (score 1):

How about an enum for the Type?

```
[Flags]
public enum Nucleotide : byte {
    undefined =0,
    A = 1,
    G = 1 << 1,
    U = 1 << 2,
    C = 1 << 3
    . . . 
    Z = 1 << 25   // of course a byte can't handle this
}
```

- Easily extensible as shown. The notation keeps me from having to actually write out the value of `2^25` for `Z`
- I can see manipulating `List<byte>` or `List<Nucleotide>` or `Stream` as needed and casting if/when necessary.
- Handy for passing to a `Factory` to build Nucleotide-specific behavior objects
- A `Nucleotide` Property in some other class effectively makes sub-classing unnecessary.
- The `Flags` attribute will allow us to define simple `Nucleotide` combinations, or even separate `enum`s of those. You can go kinda crazy abstracting bit manipulation via `enum` I suppose. Direct bitwise manipulation could mitigate execution time issues and make the code expressive in `Nucleotide` terms.
- `enums` are essentially constants and [compile to constants in IL](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-performance), i.e. good performance. [Casting is quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256713/enum-and-performance).

.

```
[Flags]
public enum Pairs : byte {
    AC = Nucleotide.A | Nucleotide.C,
    GC = Nucleotide.G | Nucleotide.C, 
    . . .
}
```

**EDIT**

@MichaelT comment got me thinking about structure vis-a-vis classification; that, and I'm with DocBrown's comment "..don't over complicate things." It seems to me that structure *is* classification.

[`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class may be useful. It is intended as a generic data structure.

```
var Phenylalanine = 
   Tuple.Create(Nucleotide.T,Nucleotide.T,Nucleotide.T);
```

"there is no practical limit to the number of components a tuple may have ... you can create tuples of eight or more elements by nesting tuple objects in the Rest property "

`Tuple` is immutable so it can be treated kinda like a singleton.

Implement [IStructuralEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable.aspx) for those codons. The 3-Tuple class [explicitly implements IStructuralEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783585.aspx).

It is Typed of course so this seems to fit the need to create types at runtime. Perhaps use a `Factory` to encapsulate a specific Tuple object with its IStructrualEquatable implementation.

Comment: What use does a pair have? A [codon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table) is a standard unit in genetics and is made up of three neucleotides, which may be repeated (TTT is  Phenylalanine).

Comment: The `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>` might prove a nice data structure to represent codons. It's typed of course, and immutable.

Comment: `[Flags]` is wrong here as 1. Nucleotide sequences are *ordered* (`AGU` != `UGA`) and (more seriously) 2. Nucleotide sequences can have duplicates!

Comment: @AakashM, yeah it occurred to me that this might be the case. Just thinkin' out loud.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following for starters.

`A`, `G`, `U`, and `C` should all derive from a base class `nucleotide` - they are specific instances of the abstract class that nucleotide represents.  In OO modeling parlance "`A` is a `nucleotide`"

This gives you the ability to extend all 4 classes of nucleotides at once, or just the individual nucleotide.

You'll need another class to model the `Strand` as a strand is composed of a series of nucleotides.  "`Strand` has a (list of) `nucleotides`".  You can likewise extend the `Strand` class to perform operations that a strand would be responsible for but that a nucleotide would not be responsible for.

I also added an interface for "just in case" purposes.  For the immediate uses, the base nucleotide class should be sufficient, but if not, then an interface is there to help guarantee behavior.

Likewise I used a `List` collection in the `Strand` so I don't have to worry about particulars such as the strand length when first modeling.  Most OO languages should have an equivalent generic collection to use.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Strand myStrand = new Strand();

        myStrand.Add(new A());
        myStrand.Add(new G());
        myStrand.Add(new U());
        myStrand.Add(new C());
    }
}

public interface INucleotide 
{
}

public class Nucleotide : INucleotide
{
    public byte TypeID;
}

public class A : Nucleotide {}
public class G : Nucleotide {}
public class U : Nucleotide {}
public class C : Nucleotide {}

public class Strand
{
    private List<INucleotide> Nucleotides = new List<INucleotide>();
    public void Add(INucleotide nuc)
    {
        Nucleotides.Add(nuc);
    }
}
```

The above sample is in C#.

Singletons really aren't appropriate for this modeling exercise - there isn't anything "single" about what you're modeling.  You'll have potentially many instantiations of `A`, `G`, `U`, and `C` as well as the `Strand`s.

Comment: But the only thing relevant about the nucleotide is "what kind is it"? It's nothing more than a `value object` as the asker uses it, and should be a good candidate for a `flyweight proxy`...

Comment: @tuespetre - we don't know the OP's particular usage. From the limited biology work I've done with RNA and DNA, there are a number of properties that may need to be modeled or considered. So that's why I presented a full OO model for the question. If we took YAGNI to the extreme here, all that's necessary is some `string`s to capture the nucleotide sequence. The OP's inference in asking for an OO model is that they are doing more than that.

Comment: (Speaking C#) If each strand is nothing more than a `List<T>` of nucleotides, and he used singleton nucleotides, he could do something like this: `var numberofgNucleotides = strand.Where(n => n == GNucleotide.Instance).Count()` which would meet the need described in the question ("I want to be able to decide the number of Nucleotide types at runtime.")

Comment: Of course, in a very light pattern, a strand could just be a queryable string, too.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a bit unclear.  When I mentioned AGCU I was just showing an example with 4 types.  I'd like to be able to, at runtime, decide to have an arbitrary number of types.  For example, have 26 types (ABCDEF... etc).

Comment: @MetaFight I suspect the problem domain (genetics) is interfering in the question that you are trying to ask and get answers to.  I have difficulty picturing the need for 26 nucleotides (or 36 if you use [A-Z0-9] or 62 of [a-zA-Z0-9] or the billion+ of unicode (without even getting into modifiers)).  But for genetics, I have difficulty seeing how this is a meaningful thing to have more than 4 (or 5 to handle T/U).

Comment: @MichaelT The goal of my application isn't to model RNA per se.  I'm using RNA as a starting point for a more general genetic system.  I need a self-replicating and self-referencing encoding system that I can use to encode anything that will need to go through darwinian evolution.  RNA seemed like a simple and logical starting point.

Comment: @MetaFight - if you're able to predefine the total number of possible types, this approach will still work.  At runtime, you would have a configuration option that says "Use X # of nucleotides" and then some control logic to limit what's instantiated for that run. However, if you need a dynamic definition of those classes at runtime then my answer will not solve your problem.